# PHP Login framework to include google/facebook/openid etc

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

In my website, i've built a login system which is quite simple.. I started implementing the facebook login option and it got a bit messy,

I'm looking for some sort of framework/code sample + db structure sample of a code that bundles the whole thing. Logins/registrations via google/facebook/openid and as many others you know of.

Stackoverflow has a very similar mechanism of what I am looking for.

Anyone knows of such a system?

Comment: not sure how helpful this would be but try this link http://oauth.net/code/

Comment: That's just for OAuth.. I am looking for something that consolidates as many reg/login options available and maybe a db structure to go with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found something called HybridAuth:
http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html

Sounds good, going to give it a try.

Also found this, for python-django:
http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/08/django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openid-yahoo-google/

Answer (score 4):

Not sure of any existing framework but this DB schema will satisfy all your expectations:

`users` table - contains all user-related fields, except of authentication ones.

Plus 1 table per each authentication system:

`auth_openid` with 2 fields `openid_token | user_id`
`auth_facebook` with `facebook_uid | user_id`

etc